# Phase abbreviations for non-aqueous solutions

Tags: nomenclature, solutions, phase

When writing a chemical equation, how do you indicate that a chemical is dissolved in a non-aqueous solvent?

For example, it would be inappropriate to write

**X (aq)**

when X is dissolved in benzene, since aq stands for "aqueous," implying water soluble. A previous answer provided the potential abbreviation **(sol)**, but I wonder if that is actually correct/commonly used.

How would you indicate that X is dissolved in a non-aqueous solvent?

Comment: In general I would specify X in benzene soln, there is no generally accepted notation for non-aqueous solution

Comment: Even if not all that common, **(sol)** stands a good chance of being understood correctly.

Comment: This is a matter of convention of course. I wonder what iupac has to say?

Answer (score 6):

According to IUPAC, general notation for *any* solution would be $\ce{X(sln)}$ [[1, p. 54](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf#page=68)]:

> **(vi) States of aggregation**
>
> The following one-, two- or three-letter symbols are used to represent the states of aggregation of chemical species [...] The letters are appended to the formula symbol in parentheses, and should be printed in Roman (upright) type without a full stop (period).
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> &\ldots\\
> &\text{s} &\text{solid}\\
> &\text{sln} &\text{solution}\\
> &\text{vit} &\text{vitreous substance}\\
> &\ldots\\
> \end{array}
> $$

Similarly, when denoting relation of a given quantity/symbol, subscript $\mathrm{sln}$ notation is used, e.g. $Δ_\mathrm{sln}G^\circ(T,p^\circ)$ [[2](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020233), pp. 241, 276]:

> **4.2 Subscripts and superscripts**
>
> *4.2.1 Subscripts*
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> &\ldots\\
> &\text{r} &\text{reference, reduced}\\
> &\text{sln} &\text{solution}\\
> &\text{s} &\text{saline solution}\\
> &\ldots\\
> \end{array}
> $$

#### References

1. IUPAC “Green Book” Quantities, Units, and Symbols in Physical Chemistry, 3rd ed.; Cohen, R. E., Mills, I., Eds.; *IUPAC Recommendations; RSC Pub: Cambridge, UK*, **2007**. ISBN 978-0-85404-433-7. ([PDF](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf))
2. Gamsjäger, H.; Lorimer, J. W.; Scharlin, P.; Shaw, D. G. Glossary of Terms Related to Solubility (IUPAC Recommendations 2008). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2008**, 80 (2), 233–276. DOI: [10.1351/pac200880020233](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020233). (Free Access)